# How to open an access database from the VBA in a Word Macro

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

All is explained in the title.

I need to be able to run a macro in word that opens up an access database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024816/access-shell-cmd-open-mdb

Comment: What have you looked into so far?  What version of Access?  Are you just trying to open the file in Access? or just read records from the tables?

Comment: @Profex I've tried doing hyperlinks i think they're called but they didnt work. Its just the latest version of Office 365, just trying to open the db, thats all, nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open and manipulate Access object, consider:

```
Public Sub OpenDB()
Dim db As Access.Application
Set db = New Access.Application
db.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\My Documents\db2.mdb"
db.Application.Visible = True 'optional
'code to manipulate Access
End Sub
```

If you just want to open an Access file and then let user interact as normal, following works for me:

```
'Shell function requires literal quote marks in the target filename string argument, apostrophe delimiters fail, hence the quadrupled quote marks
Shell SysCmd(acSysCmdAccessDir) & "MSAccess.exe " & """" & "C:\My Documents\dbname.accdb" & """", vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: To be able to use the Access object library, it will have to be added to the references in VBA.  **Tools-->References-->"Microsoft Access XX.0 Object Library"**

Comment: Right. And I just read that the file is Office 365. No idea if code will work with Office 365.

Comment: yeah, that was my next question...is access actually installed on the PC, or is it just online?  What happens when you double click the database file now?

Comment: Thank you, it is installed on the PC. The code just comes up "compile error, sub or function not defined"

Comment: Just got it to run there, it was the reference that needed added. You are literally an absolute life saver folks! Thank you so much!!!